# How to set color limits property of edgecolor for a patchcollection (python, matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting volumetric distributions with x, y and z axis (particle size, particle shape, volume (%) (z-axis as colour scale). Upon exporting the figure as svg, white space appears between the plotted rectangles. I therefore tried setting the edgecolor of the patchcollection. This works, however, the edgecolors have different clim and therefore the color of the edges differs from the patches themselves (see example figure). Code for setting the patchcollection:

```
p = PatchCollection(rects,cmap=matplotlib.cm.viridis)
colors = curem # colour of rectangles based on volume of the size-shape bins of curem
p.set_array(np.array(colors)) 
p.set_edgecolor(matplotlib.cm.viridis(np.array(colors))) 
p.set_clim([0, math.ceil(np.max(ems[ii]))]) # set maximum to max Rsqclass rounded up to next 1/5th
axs[zz].add_collection(p) # add all the rectangles to the figure
```

So how do I go about setting the color limits for the edges? Thanks in advance, Hans
[image]

Comment: Thank you for editing Bear Brown. I see that the code should go in a separate field.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a general problem with showing undesired linestrokes with vector backends, as per [this issue on matplotlib's github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9574)

A proposed temporary fix is to use very small, but non-zero linewidths:

either pass `linewidths=0.000000000001` to the constructor

```
p = PatchCollection(rects,cmap=matplotlib.cm.viridis, linewidths=0.000000000001)
```

or use

```
p.set_linewidth(0.000000000001)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this just now, however, it leads me back to my original problem, which is white space between the patches when saved as vector image (svg).

Comment: Possible solution in this thread https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9574

Comment: I tried the other option in that thread (not linewidths). That option is to set the edgecolor to 'face'. In the figure window of spyder, I see that this gives the correct color to the edges (you do not see the edges anymore). However, after rendering to svg, I still get the white space between the rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out several of Diziet Asahi's proposed solutions, I found that for this specific case, the following works:

`p.set_edgecolor('face') # edgecolor equal to facecolor
p.set_linewidth(0.5)`

The edgecolor is now equal to the facecolor. A small linewidth (e.g. the suggested 0.000000000001) does not work. White lines still appear when the svg is viewed in microsoft internet explorer or inkscape. A linewidth of 0.5 gets rid of the wite space. However, it should be noted that the required linewidth depends on the level of zoom. E.g., at 400% zoom a linewidth of 0.1 is sufficient. At 30% zoom a linewidth of 0.5 is still insufficient.

One further note: the above solution is specific to svg vector graphics. When stored as .pdf, the solution that Diziet linked to actually does work (set linewidth to an infinitesimally small value).